# Why are my apostrophes replaced with ">" in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, type

I have InDesign 2022, v. 17.2 and it randomly started giving me this issue where my apostrophes are unretrievable, instead always displaying as ">" no matter what font I'm using. Help?

[image]

Comment: It likely has something to do with your language settings on your computer, or in Indesign. Check them.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting them from Word or another word processing program? ID might not recognize the curly quotes. In that case, backspace over the > and type in the single or double quote.